# turning static multidimensional array into a dynamic one

Tags: php

I have this static array:

```
$elems = array(
  date($format, strtotime("12-12-12"))
     => array(
            "Title" => "title1",
            "Color" => "color1"),
  date($format, strtotime("12-12-11"))
     => array(
            "Title" => "title2",
            "Color" => "color2"),
);
```

which I want to turn into a dynamic array (with the same elements) .

for some reason the following code isn't good:

```
  $elems = array();
  $elems[] = date($format, strtotime("12-12-12"))
     => array(
            "Title" => "title1",
            "Color" => "color1");
  $elems[] = date($format, strtotime("12-12-11"))
     => array(
            "Title" => "title2",
            "Color" => "color2");
```

why isn't it good?
and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$elems = array();
$elems[date($format, strtotime("12-12-12"))] = array(
        "Title" => "title1",
        "Color" => "color1");
$elems[date($format, strtotime("12-12-11"))] = array(
        "Title" => "title2",
        "Color" => "color2");
```

And in general `$array = array('key' => 'value');` is the same as `$array['key'] = 'value';`.

Also take a look at [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php).

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
$elems = array();
$elems[date($format, strtotime("12-12-12"))] =  array(
    "Title" => "title1",
    "Color" => "color1"
);
```